# How can I use Elasticsearch or another search engine?

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, solr, full-text-search, algolia

I want to know which search engine is best for the following use case ?

We have an app that crawls adverts from different platforms. The users can add `searches`, with the `keyword` and other filters attributes (price, location, etc). When we receive a new advert, we want to find all the `searches` that match to the title of the advert.

Let's say you have an advert with the following title:

`I want to sale Iphone 7 plus, 16GB, black, 9/10` and use this title to query the searches collection.

Now let's say you have this searches with the following keywords:

1. `Iphone 7 16GB`
2. `Iphone 8 plus`
3. `Iphone 7 black 32GB`
4. `Iphone 7`

The main goal is to match only the: `1` and `4` searches. Because the `2` and `3` have words that are not found in the `advert` title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever the search engine you will use for this (Algolia, Elastic...), they will all allow you to do this kind of restrictive request.

For Elasticsearch, you will use a `match` clause with the `and` `operator` and the basic standard analyzer will work.

There is also a feature in Elasticsearch that allow you to store requests (aka your user keywords) and throw documents (an advert) at them to get a list of requests that match. This is called the [Percolator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html).

Comment: I looked over Percolate and I think this is what we want, but I don't figure out how we can use `match` with `and` clause ? 
`Match` with `and` will try to find all the searches that have keyword equal with advert title `I want to sale Iphone 7 plus, 16GB, black, 9/10`, right ?